# Swift: For loop to synchronous one by one until all function response

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, synchronization

I'm new to swift and practicing my best.

I have main function `appointmentCall()` when it executes and in response I may get multiple appointments. Then I pass `appointmentId` to `appointmentDetail` function for more details.

All I want to is how can I set For loop to synchronous process. Means it will not execute next appointment until first is finished. At the moment it executes all appointments.

I need appointment one by one executes all function once finished executes next appointment.

AppointmentCall 
 -> AppoinmentDetail -> processDetail -> Completed.

Code:

```
func appointmentCall(_ selectedDate:Date) {

        DataProvider.main.serviceGetAppointment(date: selectedDate, callback: {success, result in

            do{
                if(success){
                    print(result as! Data)
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let response = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: result! as! Data)
                    if let appointments = response.appointments {
                        self.appData = appointments.map { AppointmentDownloadModel(appointmentModel: $0)}
                    }
                    for eachApp in self.appData {

                        self.appointmentDetail(AppId: appId)
                    }


                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    return true
                }else{
                    return false
                }
            }catch let error {
                DataProvider.main.token = nil
                print(error as Any)
                return false
            }
        })

    }

func appointmentDetail(AppId: Int){
        DataProvider.main.serviceGetAppointmentDetail(Id: AppId , callback: {success, result in
            do{
                if(success){
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let resp = try decoder.decode(AppointmentDetail.self, from: result! as! Data)
                    self.AppDetailData = resp
                    self.processDetail(appId: AppId)
                    return true
                }else{
                    return false
                }
            }catch let error {

                print(error as Any)
                return false
            }
        })

    }



func processDetail(appId: Int) {
guard let detail = AppDetailData, AppDetailData?.appointmentId == appId else {
    return
}
for firmParam in (detail.sectionList ?? []) {
    for firmItem in firmParam.items! {
        if firmItem.actionParamData != nil {
        let str = firmItem.actionParamData
        let param = str?.components(separatedBy: ":")
        let final = param![1].replacingOccurrences(of: "}", with: "")
        let fmId = final.components(separatedBy: ",")
        let frmId = fmId[0]
        self.firmDetails(actionParamData: Int(frmId) ?? 0)
        }
        //pdf download
        if firmItem.actionType == 2 {
        if firmItem.actionUrl != nil {
        self.contentLength(link: firmItem.actionUrl!)

        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: firmItem.actionUrl ?? "")
        let fileTitle = firmItem.textField ?? ""
        self.downloadPDFTask(pdfURL: firmItem.actionUrl ?? "")

             }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you could use a recursive function that calls another function that has a completion handler, in that completion handler call the function again, and get your value from a member variable list, that way each time the function finishes it simply calls itself again and you'll know that they are been processed in order one by one only after each one has finished

Comment: @AngryDuck Can you please give example just high level Thanks?  because `appointmentDetail` is already calling in `appointmentCall` function.

Comment: see my answer for high level generic example

Answer (score 0):

If you use a recursive function with completion handler it would ensure you could essentially loop over an array and call a function to do something and know that it has completed before you do the same to your next value. See below to high level generic example

```
func doSomething()
{
    // Call this function with the first index in the array
    firstFunction(index: 0)

    // Now were here and we know that every value in the member variable array has been processed by "secondFunction"
}

func firstFunction(index: Int)
{
    let value = memberVariableArray[index]

    secondFunction(String: value) { (returnValueFromSecondFunction) in
        // do something with the return value from the second function

        // Recall this function with the next index (if we have another one)
        let newIndex = index + 1
        if newIndex < memberVariableArray.count
        {
            self.firstFunction(index: newIndex)
        }
    }
}

func secondFunction(valueToDoSomethingWith: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void)
{
    // Do something here

    // Complete function
    completion("The Value you want back")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me implement that and get back to you.

Comment: no worries I hope it helps, sorry its not specific to your example but im working on other stuff at the moment and only had time for a generic example for this type of set up!